# multiple trigger doing alert in componentWillRecieveProps

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want to alert once and redirect to somewhere if there's error in my props, I did this in my component

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

    if(nextProps.error !== '' && nextProps.error) {
      alert(nextProps.error)
      this.props.history.replace('/dashboard')
    }
  }
```

This work when I visit the route but have issue trigger multiple times if I navigate from login, I'm not sure what's the problem is.

Comment: What issues? Also, `nextProps.error !== ''` and `nextProps.error` are redundant.

Comment: Is the component getting any new props?

Comment: Are you asking why it's triggering more than once or are you asking us to help you to get it to trigger more than once?

Answer (score 0):

> componentWillReceiveProps() is invoked before a mounted component receives new props. If you need to update the state in response to prop changes (for example, to reset it), you may compare this.props and nextProps and perform state transitions using this.setState() in this method.

Without having more application code to look at it would be hard to know why your method is getting called multiple times. Without looking at anything though we know that something is causing new props to be passed to your component multiple times. However to get around it you may be able to set some state on the component to ignore running

```
alert(nextProps.error)
this.props.history.replace('/dashboard')
```

in the future when you don't want to.